# Getting KeyError in the following code to find "minimum number square to the number"

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am getting the error in the following code for the above stated problem using memoization please help me find the error and correct the code.

```
import sys
#sys.setrecursionlimit(10**5)
import math
cache={}
def m(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0

    ans=sys.maxsize
    root=int(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(1,root+1):

        nc=n-(i**2)
        if cache[nc] not in cache:
            sa=m(nc)
            cache[nc]=sa
            curr=1+sa

        else:
            curr=1+cache[nc]

        ans=min(ans,curr)

    return ans

    

print(m(int(input())))
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: I am getting Key error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you provided the full error output, which should include the line number and surrounding code. However, I suspect the issue lies in the following line:

```py
if cache[nc] not in cache:
```

You're checking whether the value of a dictionary key exists as a dictionary key. I assume you actually meant this (which will check whether a value is an existing dictionary key):

```py
if nc not in cache:
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue, now its working perfectly fine.